# Remove duplicated elements List<Vector3> Mono / C# - Unity3D

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine, mono

I need to remove the duplicates of elements in my Vector3 list.
For Example, here is a list:

```
List<Vector3> PointsToGo = new List<Vector3>();

PointsToGo.Add(new Vector3(1, 1, 1));
PointsToGo.Add(new Vector3(2, 2, 2));
PointsToGo.Add(new Vector3(1, 1, 1)); // Get this one or the first one out
PointsToGo.Add(new Vector3(4, 4, 4));
```

Do you know how to solve this problem ? Maybe Linq can help me ?

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: What is this `Vector3` class? Where does it come from?

Comment: @spender `Vector3` is one of those Unity-specific structs - basically just 3 floats (and a bunch of helper methods).

Comment: @spender A `struct` from untiy. [Here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html) is what it looks like.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is your solution

```
PointsToGo = PointsToGo.Distinct().ToList();
```

Note that you have add `using System.Linq;` to the top your code.

Comment: VS 2015 does not know the .Distinct() for Vector3. Do I need a Using Directive for it ?

Comment: You must import `using System.Linq;`

Comment: mmh, it does not look like as this works - I try it with a smaller list now.

edit: it works on a small list, but not in my big one.

Comment: @louis12356: Be careful with this method due to the floating point precision problem.

Comment: For my case its working right now, but thanks for letting me know this!

Comment: Why not implement a SortedSet, which implements a distinctives elements within the collection by default; you'd improve on performance instead of going through the Distinct extension method

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use Linq (which is a good thing according to Unity doc) you an use the following:

```
List<Vector3> list = new List<Vector3>(new HashSet<Vector3>(originalListWithDuplicate));
```

The other solution is to use HashSet collection instead. This is the purpose of that collection, avoiding duplicates. You may have to implement IEqualityComparer so it behaves exactly as you need it.

Comment: Thank you for this solution!!